# AngularJs ng-repeat multiple orderBy and with condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I have a data which contains employment history. I have two fields for my employment dateTo:

```
yearTo, monthTo
```

I need to sort the employment history correctly based on the most recent employment dateTo which I can do by

```
<tr id="employment_history_" ng-repeat="history in candidate.employmentHistory | orderBy : ['-yearTo','monthTo',] | date:['YYYY', 'MMM'] ">
```

It works correctly. But I have one problem. The field `monthTo` can also containt a value `Present` instead of just month date format `MMM` like `JAN, FEB MAR` etc.

Question how do I sort this, I understand I have a `date` format but I want the record which has the `monthTo` value `Present` to first on the list?

Comment: You are asking how to handle Present as a value in order by right?

Comment: @YogeshPatil yes. together with the dates

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle that should give you some steps in the right direction. https://jsfiddle.net/2yt04ztr/13/

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren thanks it worked. You may want to post your comment as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this JSFiddle can help you in the right direction: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2yt04ztr/13/)

The way this works is because you can give the orderBy directive an array of predicates, like you did in your provided example. In your example however you only used string predicates while you can also use function predicates. The function predicate will receive the item you're trying to order and you can choose what you want to return so angular can use that value to order the value.

```
ng-repeat="hist in main.history | orderBy: ['-yearTo', main.orderMonthTo]"

this.orderMonthTo = function(item) {
    if (item.monthTo === 'Present') {
    return -13;
  } else {
    return Number(moment(item.monthTo, 'MMM').format('M'))*-1;
  }
}
```

More information can be found about this [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).
Also, in the JSFiddle I used the [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) library to make it easier to work with dates.